# Stream over a List of Map and collect specific key

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

This is my List:

```
[
    {name: 'moe', age: 40}, 
    {name: 'larry', age: 50}, 
    {name: 'curly', age: 60}
];
```

I want to pluck `name` values and create another `List` like this:

```
["moe", "larry", "curly"]
```

I've written this code and it works:

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Map<String, Object> entry : list) {
    newList.add((String) entry.get("name"));
}
```

But how to do it in using `stream`. I've tried this code which doesn't work.

```
List<String> newList = list.stream().map(x -> x.get("name")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: FYI, these aren't json. I've just used them to represent my `List` objects.

Answer (score 10):

Since your `List` appears to be a `List<Map<String,Object>`, your stream pipeline would produce a `List<Object>`:

```
List<Object> newList = list.stream().map(x -> x.get("name")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or you could cast the value to `String` if you are sure you are going to get only `String`s:

```
List<String> newList = list.stream().map(x -> (String)x.get("name")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: this looks like `json` and there are ways to convert that to `String` instead of that `Object`... I would suggest that also

Answer (score 2):

x.get("name") should be cast to String.

for example:

`List<String> newList = list.stream().map(x -> (String) x.get("name")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1):

If `list` from your iterator has type of `Map<String, Object>` then I think that the best way to do that task is just invoke method `keySet()` which will return `Set` but you can create `ArrayList` from it in the following way:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList(list.keySet());
```